# Angular 2 + Material 2 Toolbar nested Sidenav - How Call toggle button outside Sidenav

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-material2

I have SidenavComponent and ToolbarComponent nested

I would like to call sidenav.toggle () outside the SidenavComponent inside ToolbarComponent

**sidenav.component.html**

```
 <md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" color="primary">
     <md-toolbar color="primary"><span>Sidenav</span></md-toolbar>
        <button md-button class="sidenav-link" (click)="sidenav.close()">HOME</button>
      </md-sidenav>

      <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>

    </md-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**toolbar.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button md-button class="toolbar-menu-button"
          (click)="sidenav.toggle()" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <md-icon [@iconChange]="isCollapsed">menu</md-icon>
  </button>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
  <button md-button class="toolbar-link" >HOME</button>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
</md-toolbar>
```

**toolbar.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
import {SidenavComponent} from '../sidenav/sidenav.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('iconChange', [
      state('true',
        style({ transform: 'rotate( -90deg )' })
      ),
      state('false',
        style({ transform: 'rotate( 0deg )' })
      ),
      transition('* => *', animate('.25s'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How do i call sidenav.toggle() in toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the reference `#sidenav` as an `Input` to your `app-toolbar` component.

toolbar.component.ts:

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sidenav;

}
```

sidenav.component.html:

```
<app-toolbar [sidenav]="sidenav"></app-toolbar>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuq5LBayQOcOtiu3Riqo?p=preview)

Also, I suggest changing

```
(click)="sidenav.toggle()" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
```

to

```
(click)="sidenav.toggle(); isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
```

You don't need to have a separate `click` event for each

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the logic from the template, you keep it MVC.

Use ViewChild to reference the sidenav:

Class:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
....
@ViewChild('sidenav') private sidenav;
...
onClick(){
 this.sidenav.toggle();
 this.collapsed=!this.collapsed;
 //any other action
}
```

HTML:

```
 <button md-button class="toolbar-menu-button" (click)="onClick()">
```